# Flutter - Watch network metrics of WebSocket

Tags: android, flutter, dart, websocket

I have a very simple project. I have a FastApi backend server running on localhost and listening for websockets. In my Flutter application, I connect to the socket with the following line:

```
var channel = IOWebSocketChannel.connect('ws://127.0.0.1:3000/ws/$client_id'); //client_id is just a UUID
```

I also listen for any incoming messages and ack the server with the same message:

```
channel.stream.listen((message) {
    print('Received: $message');

    // Echo back the received message to the server
    channel!.sink.add(message);
  });
```

I implemented a ping-pong mechanism between the server and the client. Client initiates the process with the following function:

```
void emitMessage(num) {
    channel!.sink.add(num);
  }
```

In the backend, whenever client triggers emitMessage() function, a for loop starts with 1 second of sleep in each iteration. It counts from 0 to given number (by client) and sends a message to client with each increment. Server than waits for client to respond before continuing with the next iteration. And because client echoes whatever it receives back to server, the process goes on synchronously (can't share the algorithm due to some privacy problems. Though it's not very relevant to my question.)

In other words, client and server plays ping-pong for the given number of iterations.

My goal is to monitor the network metrics of this process. I tried using the Android Studio Flutter DevTools' network tab. However, it looks like socket communication is not logged there. I want to see stuff like response time, payload size, etc.

Any ideas/suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

In the newest version of DevTools there is a way to inspect your WebSocket connections but only in a general way.

To have more enhanced details about current WS connection it's good to use external tools such as Charles: [Inspect WebSocket packages with Charles proxy in Flutter app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70683726/inspect-websocket-packages-with-charles-proxy-in-flutter-app)

In an attachment there is a screenshot from Flutter DevTools and Networking section with possible data to read.
[image]